# SSL (TLS v1.2) issues with IntelliJ 2017.3 and GitHub

Tags: ssl, github, intellij-idea, tls1.2

So with the recent weak crypto standards removal at GitHub I can no longer use GitHub with IntelliJ. I've done some research and so far it seems that IntelliJ does not support TLSv1.2?

The only SSL protocols I'm seeing are SSLv3 and TLSv1 in the Network settings of Version Control.

[Subversion > Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKT2u.png)

Is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000051964

Comment: Edit: It still doesn't work, I updated to 2018.1 EAP and set the SSH executable to Native. Same problem, I really need a solution for this. I've also updated my Git and Git Creditional Manager to the latest versions.

Comment: In 2018.1, you don't need to switch to native. If you want to use Native - most likely you will need to load keys to the ssh-agent first

Comment: See https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/02/26/update-on-ssh-access-to-github-in-intellij-based-ides/ for an official update on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS is used in HTTPs connections only. IntelliJ does support TLS v.1.2

The issue is that you probably use SSH, and builtin SSH client indeed fails to connect after `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` has been disabled on the GitHub.

The issue is [fixed in 2018.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140196)

If you don't want to update to the EAP yet, as a workaround you could switch SSH executable to Native at `Settings | Version Control | Git`. Note, that if you keys are protected with a passphrase, you need to load them into ssh-agent first. See e.g. [this topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase)

Comment: Which works for OS X, but doesn't work for Windows sadly. Just updated Git to 2.16.2 (Git for Windows).

Comment: Hesistant to update, as last time I updated (from 2016.x to 2017.x) I lost _all_ my settings with no way to recover them.

Comment: Should work for windows just needs proper configuration. See e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase

Comment: Settings of the older installation are always left intact in the corresponding config folder. The new version just uses new folder for all the stuff, and if you chose not to migrate settings, uses defaults. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs for more information on folders used

Answer (score 1):

we can try this.
set VM Option in Intellij Idea with the following code:
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: You should go into more detail to make the answer more easily understandable, mostly where to put the code and how to reach the menu(s) to do so, and the version you are using because maybe your solution breaks in a future update.

Comment: VM options can be set as per this resource - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Answer (score 0):

Update VM Option in Android Studio

File:- studio.vmoptions

**Add below line**

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```